# passing in options to solvers from cvxr solve function

Tags: r, optimization, solver, convex-optimization, cvxr

I am using CVXR to solve a problem with constrains.  The solver gives result that doesn't satisfy all constrains.

```
result <- solve(problem, solver='ECOS', verbose=TRUE, ecos.control(maxit=2000))
```

The last few lines of verbose output is like below:

> **100**  +3.405e+04  +3.405e+04  +1e-09  5e-05  5e-09  1e-03  4e-12  0.9791  9e-01   2  0  0 | 15  0
>   Maximum number of iterations reached, recovering best iterate (87) and stopping.

The solver stopped at iteration 100, which could be the reason that the solution doesn't satisfy the constrain; or could be that the problem's solution is small number (1e-5) and the default tolerance was hit.
So I tried to pass in extra argument into the solver according to document of package ECOSolveR:

```
ecos.control(maxit=2000)
```

Yet, the solver still stops at default maximum iteration of 100.  What went wrong?  How do I pass extra controls to the solver?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The arguments should be all capital letters.

```
result <- solve(problem, solver='ECOS', verbose=TRUE, MAXIT=as.integer(2000))
```

I think this is inconsistent with the document.